# Make condition when have equal values in a column

Tags: r

Note that `k` is the value of `n`, where `Mode` is equal to `1`. However, in this case below, I have two values ​​where `Mode` is equal to `1`, which is `n = 2` and `n = 4`. So I would like to make some condition or something like that, that this will happen, considering the case where `M1` is equal to `1`, in this case, the first alternative, that is, `n = 2`. So `k` would be equal to 2.

```
df1<-structure(list(n= c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
    12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20), M1 = c(1L, 3L, 2L, 19L, 
    18L, 16L, 17L, 14L, 15L, 13L, 12L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
    4L, 5L), M2 = c(1L, 3L, 2L, 19L, 18L, 16L, 17L, 14L, 
    15L, 13L, 12L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 4L, 5L), M3 = c(3L, 
    2L, 1L, 19L, 18L, 16L, 17L, 14L, 15L, 13L, 12L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 
    10L, 11L, 4L, 5L), M4 = c(2L, 3L, 1L, 19L, 18L, 16L, 
    17L, 14L, 15L, 13L, 12L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 4L, 5L), Mode = c(1, 
    3, 1, 19, 18, 16, 17, 14, 15, 13, 12, 7, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 4, 
    5), Percentage = c("50%", "75%", "50%", "100%", "100%", "100%", 
    "100%", "100%", "100%", "100%", "100%", "100%", "100%", "100%", 
    "100%", "100%", "100%", "100%", "100%")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -19L))

    n M1 M2 M3 M4 Mode Percentage
1   2  1  1  3  2    1        50%
2   3  3  3  2  3    3        75%
3   4  2  2  1  1    1        50%
4   5 19 19 19 19   19       100%
5   6 18 18 18 18   18       100%
6   7 16 16 16 16   16       100%
7   8 17 17 17 17   17       100%
8   9 14 14 14 14   14       100%
9  10 15 15 15 15   15       100%
10 11 13 13 13 13   13       100%
11 12 12 12 12 12   12       100%
12 13  7  7  7  7    7       100%
13 14  6  6  6  6    6       100%
14 15  8  8  8  8    8       100%
15 16  9  9  9  9    9       100%
16 17 10 10 10 10   10       100%
17 18 11 11 11 11   11       100%
18 19  4  4  4  4    4       100%
19 20  5  5  5  5    5       100%

k<-subset(df1, Mode==1)$n 

> k
[1] 2 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`match` is a good way to find the first `n` for which `Mode == 1`

```
k = with(df1[order(df1$M1), ], n[match(1, Mode)])
k
# [1] 2
```

Change `df1[order(df1$M1), ]` to `df1[order(df1$M1, df1$M2, df1$M3, ...), ]` if you want to use additional columns as tie breakers.

If you need to generalize this to modes that are not first in the default sort order (like `1` is in your sample data), do it like this:

```
m = 1
k = with(df1[order(df1$M1 == m, decreasing = TRUE), ], n[match(m, Mode)])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Gregor. But if `M1 = 1` is in the 3rd alternative and not in the first one, then `k` would be equal to 4. In this case, your code wouldn't work, right?

Comment: Oh, now I see what you mean. Sort your data by `M1` (and the other `M` columns too if you want more tie breakers) so that the first match is the alternative that you want. Updating the answer...

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted Gregor, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Gregor, a question, please: I got 2 or 4 in `k` in the first code. And If I always want it to take the smallest value of `n`, what would it look like?

Comment: Sort by `n` to get the smallest value of `n`.

Comment: Gregor, I think I could do that too, right? `k<-subset(df1, Mode==1)$n` and after do `k = k[1]`

Comment: Yes, that's another option. Many ways to do things.

Comment: If you look back in the edit history of my answer, that's what I thought your problem was. `df1$n[match(1, df1$Mode)]` will be more efficient than `subset()`.